# MongoDB group withm multi-field

Tags: php, mongodb, group-by

Now I have a mongodb like this structure：

```
{
   _id:
   content:{
            A:a
            B:....
           }

   _id:
   content:{
            C:a
            D:....
           }

   _id:
   content:{
            C:c
            D:....
           }
}
```

I need to sum content.A and content.C. And sort the result to get top 5.
Expect result like this:

```
a:2
c:1
```

Give me the Example.Better use php mongo query pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: { $ifNull: [ "$content.A", "$content.C" ] }, // use "A" if it's available otherwise use "C"
        count: { $sum: 1 } // count documents per group
    }
}, {
    $sort: { "count": -1 } // sort descending
}, {
    $limit: 5 // get top 5 only
})
```

Comment: Thank you.Ur answer is what i need.